# what is difference between batch size in data pipeline and batch size in midel.fit()?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, data-science, batchsize

Are these 2 the same batch-size, or they have different meaning?

```
BATCH_SIZE=10
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

2nd

```
history = model.fit(train_ds,
  epochs=EPOCHS,                    
  validation_data=create_dataset(X_valid, y_valid_bin),
  max_queue_size=1,
  workers=1,
  batch_size=10,
  use_multiprocessing=False)
```

I'm having problem of Ram out of run...
Traning images example 333000
Ram 30GB
12 GB GPU
What should be the batch size for this?

[Full Code Here](https://github.com/mobinalhassan/Multi-label-image-classification/blob/master/iMaterialist%20c-2020.ipynb)

Comment: The first example creates a generator that yields a batch of 10 filenames at a time. You can use this along with a generator function in `model.fit` method. The second example should also create a batch of 10 images and train your model on each batch sequentially. Possibly, your validation data is too big.

Comment: @TirthPatel both need to be given

Comment: I know that both the training and validation sets can be passed to keras model's `fit` method but you can customize that using custom generator functions. What I am saying is, have you tried to look into your validation data and see its size. You can also batch your validation data in keras. [This thread discusses that in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48724122/validation-data-batch-size-of-size-one-keras)

Comment: @TirthPatel Yes! validation data-set was large..

Comment: I have limited validation dataset to 300 but still fill whole ram, I'm going to add git repo link in question you can check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data-Set (Batch Size)**

Batch size only mean that how much data will pass through a pipeline you defined. In the case of Dateset batch size represent how much data will be passed to the model in one iteration. For-example if you form a data generator and set batch size 8. Now on every iteration data generator give 8 data records.

**Model.fit (Batch Size)**

and in the model.fit when we set batch size it means that model will calculate loss after passing data-records equal to the batch-size. If you know about deep learning models they will calculate a particular loss on feed forward and than through back propagation they improves themselves. Now if you set batch-size 8 in model.fit now 8 data-records are pass to the model and loss is calculated of that 8 data-records and than model improve from that loss.

**Example:**

Now if you set dateset batch-size equal to 4 and set model.fit batch-size equal to 8. Now your dateset generator has to iterate 2 times to give 8 images to model and model.fit only perform 1 iteration to calculate loss.

**Ram Issue**

what is your image size ? Try to reduce batch_size because step per epochs are not related to ram but batch size is. Because if you are giving 10 batch size than 10 images have to load onto the ram for processing and your ram is not capable of loading 10 images at the same time. Try to give batch size 4 or 2. that may help you

Comment: Good I understand but,
Actually I'm facing problem of RAM out of run..
so i try STEPS_PER_EPOCH parameter too...

STEPS_PER_EPOCH=total_no_img/batch_size 

STEPS_PER_EPOCH=50000/10

STEPS_PER_EPOCH=5000

Still too much to fit in ram?
Here i'm only reading 50000 records from file.

Comment: According to your answer we need to give batch size in both place?

Comment: what is your image size ? Try to reduce batch_size because step per epochs are not related to ram but batch size is. Because if you are giving 10 batch size than 10 images have to load onto the ram for processing and your ram is not capable of loading 10 images at the same time. Try to give batch size 4 or 2. that may help you.

Comment: image size (240,240,3)

Comment: 12 gb of ram not able to load 10 images of input(240,240,3). reduce batch size upto 4.